# Find all numbers in a string in Python 3

Tags: python, string, int, cal

Newbie here, been searching the net for hours for an answer.

```
string = "44-23+44*4522" # string could be longer
```

How do I make it a list, so the output is:

```
[44, 23, 44, 4522]
```

Comment: Take a look at the `re` module and `split`, where you could split on the operators.

Comment: I *really* don't believe that you've been searching the net for hours. Typing your *exact* question title into Google yields me the answer.

Comment: I promise you. Been using at least 2 hours on searching for this.

Thanks for fast repons!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the regular expressions as suggested by AChampion, you can do the following.

```
string = "44-23+44*4522"
import re
result = re.findall(r'\d+',string)
```

The r'' signifies raw text, the '\d' find a decimal character and the + signifies 1 or more occurrences. If you expect floating points in your string that you don't want to be separated, you might what to bracket with a period '.'.

```
re.findall(r'[\d\.]+',string)
```

Comment: The only thing to add would be if the OP needs a list of ints `result = [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+',string)]` or `result = [int(i) for i in re.split('[+-*/]', string)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have your made up function, explained and detailed.
**Since you're a newbie, this is a very simple approach so it can be easily understood.**

```
def find_numbers(string):
    list = []
    actual = ""
    # For each character of the string
    for i in range(len(string)):
        # If is number
        if "0" <= string[i] <= "9":
            # Add number to actual list entry
            actual += string[i]
        # If not number and the list entry wasn't empty
        elif actual != "":
            list.append(actual);
            actual = "";
    # Check last entry
    if actual != "":
        list.append(actual);
    return list
```

Comment: This is considered easy?